# Rewind in HLS Stream using JWPlayer SDK for Android

Tags: android, jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer SDK for Android to stream a HLS stream. This is from their blog

> JW Player SDK for iOS and Android 2.2 now both support DVR functionality in HLS live streams so developers can offer their app users the ability to pause & rewind for HLS live video streams; our Android SDK additionally supports DVR for MPEG-DASH streams.

I am using this

```
JWPlayerFragment fragment = (JWPlayerFragment) 
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.playerFragment);
    JWPlayerView playerView = fragment.getPlayer();
    playerView.setControls(true);
    PlaylistItem video = new PlaylistItem(url);
    playerView.load(video);
```

To stream my HLS stream. How do we achieve the rewind feature of HLS live streams ?

Answer (score 0):

Your HLS stream needs to be DVR enabled. Here's an example of a DVR enabled stream:

https://wowza.jwplayer.com/live/jelly.stream/playlist.m3u8?dvr

Please reach out to your streaming provider for information on how to enable DVR on your streams.